# if option is not selected statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have dropdown select and options like this:

```
<div class="input-field">
 <span class="icon-area"></span>
 <select>
  <option value="0">list 0</option>
  <option value="1">list 2</option>
  <option value="2">list 3</option>
 </select>
```

and if list 0 is not selected I want to add css style it but my js code doesn't work

```
$("select").blur(function() {
        $(this).parents(".input-field").removeClass("form-border");
        $(this).parents(".input-field").find(".icon-area").removeClass("form-background");

        if(this.value){
            $(this).parents(".input-field").addClass("form-border");
            $(this).parents(".input-field").find(".icon-area").addClass("form-background");
            return false;
        }else{
            $(this).parents(".input-field").removeClass("form-border");
            $(this).parents(".input-field").find(".icon-area").removeClass("form-background");
            return false;
        }
    });
```

what is wrong ?

Comment: `this.value` probably needs to be `$(this).val()`

Comment: `$(this).val() !="0"` can be shortened to `$(this).val()`. Everything in jQuery is truthy, unless `0` is meant to represent "no value."

Comment: `this.value` returns string, and `"0"` is truthly in js. Only string empty is falsy string

Comment: @DrewKennedy No, `$(this).val()` returns string `"0"` which is truthly value. So it cannot be shortened this way

Comment: @A.Wolff Right. I made the comment before realizing there was no option with an absent value. I'm leaving it up because the OP can learn something from this conversation. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try replacing with this:

```
$("select").change(function() {
        $(this).parents(".input-field").removeClass("form-border");
        $(this).parents(".input-field").find(".icon-area").removeClass("form-background");

        if(this.value==0){
            $(this).parents(".input-field").addClass("form-border");
            $(this).parents(".input-field").find(".icon-area").addClass("form-background");
            return false;
        }else{
            $(this).parents(".input-field").removeClass("form-border");
            $(this).parents(".input-field").find(".icon-area").removeClass("form-background");
            return false;
        }
    });
```